# ¿Cómo puedo usar el tamaño de un arreglo en C++ como un int?

Tags: c++, array, sizeof

Tengo una función que toma un arreglo. Lo toma de esta manera:

```
std::vector<int>
```

Necesito usar en la función el tamaño de ese arreglo. Para hacer cálculos con los elementos, el problema es que intento usar `sizeof();` pero me devuelve no el peso de todos los elementos sino que otro número.

He usado por poco tiempo C++, así que si tienen alguna corrección que hacerme ¡sea bienvenida!

Comment: Sera muy difícil ayudarte si no vemos aunque sea una fracción de tu código, edita tu pregunta para  que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el método [`std::vector::size()`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) para ello. Ejemplo:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl; // devuelve 0
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(10);
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl; // devuelve 2
```

`sizeof()` por el contrario te devuelve el tamaño, en bytes, del tipo de dato o variable indicada.

---

Si lo que necesitas es el tamaño total de los elementos del vector puedes simplemente hacer

```
size_t total_size = v.size() * sizeof(int);
```

O bien, si usas C++11 en adelante, usar `decltype` para hacer algo más genérico el código (`vector<T>::value_type` indica el tipo del elemento del vector):

```
auto total_size = v.size() * decltype(v)::value_type;
```

---

Es importante no confundir con los arreglos (*arrays* en inglés). Más información sobre los arreglos [acá (en inglés)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array). Por otra parte, sí es posible calcular el número de elementos de un arreglo estático (definido en tiempo de compilación) usando `sizeof`:

```
int a[100];
std::cout << (sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)) << std::endl;
```

El tamaño en bytes del arreglo es (100 * tamaño del entero), por lo que basta con dividir por el tamaño del elemento, lo que da 100.

Comment: Creo que Luis Mario Ramirez necesita el peso (tamaño) del vector, no la cantidad de elementos.

Comment: Gracias, he actualizado la respuesta para incluir ese escenario en caso de que fuera lo que el OP preguntaba

Answer (score 2):

#### Problema.

> El problema es que intento usar `sizeof()`; pero me devuelve no el peso de todos los elementos sino que otro número.

El operador [`sizeof`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) devuelve el tamaño en bytes del objeto, tipo o expresión facilitado, así que aplicando `sizeof` sobre el vector te devolverá el tamaño en bytes del objeto vector.

#### ¡Vamos a comer pulpos y gambas!

Como analogía imagina que `sizeof` contase la cantidad de patas de un animal, si aplicas `sizeof` sobre un pulpo te indicaría `8`. Ahora imagina que tú y yo nos vamos a una marisquería y yo me como 5 [gambas al ajillo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambas_al_ajillo) y tú te comes un [pulpo a la gallega](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulpo_a_la_gallega).

Ahora hago `sizeof` de ti y `sizeof` de mi; si tú has comido pulpo debería devolver `8` y si yo he comido gambas debería devolver `50` (cada gamba tiene 10 patas) pero devuelve ¡`2` y `2`!.

Esto sucede, tal y como he indicado, porque `sizeof` evalúa el objeto, no lo que el objeto contiene<sup>1</sup>, así que evalúa las patas tuyas y mías (probablemente `2` en ambos casos) no las patas del contenido de nuestro buche.

#### Tamaño (en bytes) de un `std::vector<int>`.

Para conocer el tamaño (en bytes) de un `std::vector<int>` no debes aplicar `sizeof` sobre el objeto, si no que debes aplicar `sizeof` sobre el dato contenido y multiplicarlo por la cantidad de elementos; siguiendo con nuestra analogía:

```
Luis_Mario_Ramirez.cuantos_pulpos_ha_comido() * sizeof(Pulpo); // Seria 1 * 8 = 8
PaperBirdMaster.cuantas_gambas_ha_comido() * sizeof(Gamba); // Seria 5 * 10 = 50
```

Y en código real sería:

```
int funcion(std::vector<int> arreglo)
{
    return arreglo.size() * sizeof(int);
}
```

`funcion` nos indicará cuantos bytes tiene ocupados `arreglo`, pero no nos indicará cuantos bytes usa. Los `std::vector` (y otros contenedores similares) reservan más espacio del que usan para reducir las operaciones de re-alojamiento de memoria<sup>2</sup>, si quieres saber el tamaño que está usando un `std::vector<int>` (no el que está ocupando) deberías usar [`std::vector::capacity`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity):

```
int funcion(std::vector<int> arreglo)
{
    return arreglo.capacity() * sizeof(int);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Esto es una simplificación del tema, en realidad es más complejo.

<sup>2</sup>Si quieres más información de esto, haz otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es saber la cantidad de elementos que hay en dicho vector utiliza la funcion `size()` por ejemplo supongamos tenemos un vector y le ingresamos unos cuantos numeros

```
vector<int> misEnteros;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    misEnteros.push_back(i);
}
```

Aqui hemos ingresado numeros del 0 hasta el 9, para saber la cantidad de elementos seria

```
cout<<"Tamaño: "<<misEnteros.size()<<'\n';
```

La salida seria: `Tamaño: 10`

Comment: En realidad el tamaño sería `40`, asumiendo 4 bytes por cada `int`.